# Delete a single line if a specific string is found

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm fairly new with IIB, currently what I want to achieve is to delete a single line from a TXT if it contains a specific word for example the word **USA** as per below.I read it as a BLOB then convert it to a string. Should I achieve this using Compute node or Java node? Thanks in advance.

e.g

Before

```
Hello my name 
is Malcom and I live
in the USA
```

After

```
Hello my name 
is Malcom and I live
```

**Current Flow**
FileInput -> Compute -> JavaCompute -> FileOutput

FileInput : To read data from a specific folder

Compute   : Replace a    string to another string (mask)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getBLOBMessage() BEGIN
        DECLARE fullBLOB CHARACTER;
        SET fullBLOB = CAST(OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB as char CCSID 1208 Encoding 815);
        SET OutputLocalEnvironment.msg = fullBLOB;
    END;
    
    CREATE PROCEDURE maskMessage(INOUT msg CHARACTER) BEGIN
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, '431.111.55.113', 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, '111.115.11.112', 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, '111.112.11.112', 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, '111.111.111.116', 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, '172.16.18.72', 'XXX.XX.XX.XX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, 'b1111111110', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, '11111111101', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, '11111111111', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, 'B1111111111', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, 'Q1111111', 'XXXXXXXX');
         SET msg = REPLACE (msg, '11111111111N', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'); 
         SET OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB = CAST (msg AS BLOB CCSID 1208 Encoding 815);
    END;
```

JavaCompute: For removing line maybe?

FileOutput: To generate the output txt file

Comment: Why not treat each input line as a record (File Input -> Record detection = Delimited,  Delimiter = <your line ending of the file>) and then only forward the record to the File Output node if it does not contain your pattern? This way you can easily do it in ESQL.

Comment: Do you mind explaning a bit more? Im still new to the IIB sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Record detection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac55150_.htm) feature of the File Input node, your requirements can be fulfilled in ESQL.

FileInput node:

- Records and Elements: Record detection = Delimited
- Connect `End of Data` to `Finish File` of FileOutput node

Compute node:

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE Thaqif_Compute

    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;
        DECLARE line CHARACTER CAST(OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB AS CHAR
                                    CCSID InputProperties.CodedCharSetId
                                    ENCODING InputProperties.Encoding);
        IF CONTAINS(line, 'USA') THEN
            RETURN FALSE;
        ELSE
            CALL maskMessage(line);
            SET OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB = CAST(line AS BLOB 
                                            CCSID InputProperties.CodedCharSetId
                                            ENCODING InputProperties.Encoding);
            RETURN TRUE;
        END IF;
    END;

    CREATE PROCEDURE maskMessage(INOUT msg CHARACTER) BEGIN
        SET msg = REPLACE (msg, '431.111.55.113', 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX');
        -- Other patterns removed for brevity
        SET msg = REPLACE (msg, 'Q1111111', 'XXXXXXXX');
    END;

END MODULE;
```

FileOutput node:

- Records and Elements: Record definition = Record is delimited data

Example input:

```
Hello my name 
is Malcom and I live
in the USA
where 431.111.55.113 is masked
but Q2222222 is still ok
```

Resulting output:

```
Hello my name 
is Malcom and I live
where XXX.XXX.XX.XXX is masked
but Q2222222 is still ok
```